# How do I return Max procedure Run Date) and Total Procedure Counts in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, system

Is there a way to determine (after the fact or in the past X time frame) how many times each stored procedure, function or view has been called in a database? When was the Maximum/last run date for the store procedure?

Basically I want to say

```
Use databaseABC
select procedurename, count(howManyTimesItsBeenCalled), max(lastRunDate) 
from the databseABC
```